# A problem in deriving Lorentz transformation from homogeneity and isotropy of spacetime and the principle of relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

I'm trying to understand a step in a derivation of the Lorentz transformation, that my professor gave in class. We start assuming the homogeneity and the isotropy of the 4 dimensional spacetime and then we consider two inertial frames of reference $S$ and $S'$, with $S'$ moving at speed $v$ along the $x$-axis of $S$. We also assume that $S$ and $S'$ have parallel axes and their origins coincide at time $t=0$ in $S$. So a general transformation between the coordinates of $S$ and $S'$ respectively is,
\begin{align}
t\qquad &\to\qquad t'=T(t,x,y,z,v)\\
x\qquad &\to\qquad x'=X(t,x,y,z,v)\\
y\qquad &\to\qquad y'=Y(t,x,y,z,v)\\
z\qquad &\to\qquad z'=Z(t,x,y,z,v) \ .
\end{align}
Then, applying homogeneity we find that the transformation must be linear, so
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}t'\\x'\\y'\\z'\end{pmatrix}=A(v)\begin{pmatrix}t\\x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \ ,
\end{equation}
where $A(v)$ is a $4\times4$ matrix. Using the principle of relativity we find that directions perpendicular to the motion don't change, so
\begin{equation}
A(v)=\begin{pmatrix}A_1(v)&A_2(v)\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}\end{pmatrix} \ ,
\end{equation}
where $A_1(v)$ and $A_2(v)$ are $2\times 2$ matrices, and $\mathbf{0}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $\mathbf{1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Now comes the step that I don't understand, it says that:

> *From the isotropy of space, follows that $A_2(v)=\mathbf{0}$*

Can please someone help me to understand how the isotropy of space have this implication?

Comment: $A(v)$ is a boost in the $x$ direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling there should be a physical reason for the off-diagonal elements both having to be zero, but I can't think of one off-hand. Here's another way to show it, though:

Consider, for example, a point particle whose rest frame is $S^\prime$. To you, the observer sitting in $S$, this particle would be moving away along your $x$ axis. Now, what about the $y$ and $z$ axes? Well, they shouldn't be important here, as these directions are orthogonal to the motion of the particle. In other words, once you have chosen your $x$ axis to be along the direction of motion of the particle, you have an infinite number of $y$ and $z$ axes that can be chosen -- all related by simple rotations around the $x$-axis -- which *must* all give the same $A(v)$ matrix. This is one of the assumptions of isotropy.

Suppose, instead of the $(t,x,y,z)$  you used $(t,x,Y,Z)$, where $Y$ and $Z$ are two *different* mutually perpendicular directions that are *also* perpendicular to $x$. Since space is isotropic, your definition of $y$ and $z$ should not affect your transformation matrix, and so

$$\begin{pmatrix}t^\prime\\x^\prime\end{pmatrix} = A_1(v) \begin{pmatrix}t\\x\end{pmatrix} + A_2(v) \begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}t^\prime\\x^\prime\end{pmatrix}  = A_1(v)\begin{pmatrix}t\\x\end{pmatrix} + A_2(v) \begin{pmatrix}Y\\Z\end{pmatrix}$$

Or $$A_2(v) \begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix} = A_2(v) \begin{pmatrix}Y\\Z\end{pmatrix}$$

It should be intuitively clear that since $Y$ and $Z$ could be any possible orthogonal set (also orthogonal to $x$), this *must* mean that $A_2(v)=\mathbf{0}$, but if you wish to be a little more rigorous, these new $Y,Z$ axes can be obtained from $y,z$ by rotation of some angle $\theta$ around the $x$ axis, and so

$$\begin{pmatrix}Y\\Z\end{pmatrix} = R(\theta) \begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix},$$ where $R(\theta)$ is the usual rotation matrix. The above equality then means that for any arbitrary value of $\theta$,

$$A_2(v) \left(\mathbf{1} - R(\theta) \right) = \mathbf{0}.$$

Since $\theta$ and $v$ are both arbitrary, it must be that $A_2(v) = \mathbf{0}$.

Comment: So if the $A(v)$ is a boost in a general direction, space is no longer isotropic?

Comment: I don't quite understand, the Lorentz transformations do distinguish between the direction parallel to the boost and those perpendicular to it. If the boost were in a general direction, then one could always rotate one's coordinate system to be along that direction and call it $x$, and the same argument I made would hold.

I think the exact argument could also be made for a general transformation, by defining a direction $\hat{n}$ and two orthogonal basis vectors $Y,Z$ that are perpendicular to $\hat{n}$...

Comment: $$ A(v)=\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\beta_x\gamma & -\beta_y\gamma & -\beta_z\gamma\\
-\beta_x\gamma & 1+\frac{\beta_{x}^{2}(\gamma-1)}{\beta^{2}} &
  \frac{\beta_{x}\beta_{y}(\gamma-1)}{\beta^{2}} & \frac{\beta_{x}\beta_{z}(\gamma-1)}{\beta^{2}} & \\ -\beta_y\gamma & \frac{\beta_{x}\beta_{y}(\gamma-1)}{\beta^{2}} & 1+\frac{\beta_{y}^{2}(\gamma-1)}{\beta^{2}} & \frac{\beta_{y}\beta_{z}(\gamma-1)}{\beta^{2}}& \\
-\beta_z\gamma &\frac{\beta_{x}\beta_{z}(\gamma-1)}{\beta^{2}}& \frac{\beta_{y}\beta_{z}(\gamma-1)}{\beta^2}&1+\frac{\beta_{z}^2(\gamma-1)}{\beta^{2}} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Setting $\beta_{y}=\beta_{z}=0$ in $A(v)$ above will generate the OP's $A_{1}(v)$ and $A_{2}(v)$.

Comment: Yes, the Lorentz transformations do distinguish between the direction parallel to the boost and those perpendicular to it. But there are $2$ vectors- namely, $\vec \beta$ and $\vec r$ - and there's no reason why the vectors have to be co-linear - other then for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: I agree, but I'm afraid I don't quite get the point: in the OP's post, the assumption was not the most general one, but one in which $\beta$ was only along $x$. Is there anything wrong or misleading with my answer?

Comment: Thank you! Very clear!

Comment: @Philip: you just need to careful when considering more then one boost since two boost create a rotation. And I don't believe the OP can prove space is isotropic mathematically. Locally, it can inferred from conservation of linear and angular momentum. But in general relativity, it isn't that simple - homogeneity and the isotropy of space are typically assumed and conservation of linear and angular momentum demonstrated.

Comment: @Philip - actually, I just realized I misread the post - the OP assumes the isotropy of space - my bad. In which case, I presume the OP just didn't realize when the boost is in the $x$ direction, the boost plane is $t-x$ - and it doesn't include the other coordinates. You were right.